# Excel Copy value of different columns to one depending on substring of a column

Tags: excel-formula

I can't seem to find what I'm looking for and I just can't make it work with the partially correct Answers I find.

So I have an Excel file with empty column A. A lot of data is pasted in columns B to E

I need Excel to check if the data (text) in column be start with "C0". If it does, it needs to add this value to the field in the same row of column A. If column B does not start with "C0", Column A should get the value of column C (which is also text).

The only solutions I find are for integers or for whole strings. In this case the value in column B is a text and somehow can't fix it to look for only beginning with "C0", it always wants to check the whole value or doesn't check at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in A2:

```
=IF(Left(B2,2) = "C0",B2,C2)
```

Comment: What error? And what is you local setup?  You may need to change out all the `,` for `;` Depending on your local setup. @coasterfrenzy

Comment: To be clear: After checking if column B starts with "C0", the whole field should be copied, not only the substring.

Comment: That is exactly what it is doing. @coasterfrenzy

Comment: I get the standard error: "The formula you typed contains an error"..I don't know what you mean with the local setup. But thank you very much: It works with ; in

Comment: @coasterfrenzy In countries that use `,` as the deliminator between integers and decimal use `;` as separator.  In Countries like mine where we use `.` instead of `,` we use the `,` in our formulas.